# Http код ошибки 403

Tags: http, curl, https, http2

Подскажите пожалуйста, по какой причине сервер может так себя вести:

-Ввожу в браузере название сайта, браузер без проблем открывает его.

-Теперь делаю "тоже самое", только с помощью библиотеки libcurl, однако в этом случае сервер отвечает HTTP/2 403.

Вроде, как - проблема не в либе, так как другие сайты без проблем отдают страницу на запросы черех libcurl.

Как понять почему так ?

Comment: Потому что сервер запрещает обращаться к себе через libcurl, видимо

Comment: @andreymal, а как он понимает, что я через libcurl обращаюсь ?

Comment: Ошибка 403 означает что у вас нет доступа к данному материалу.

Comment: User-Agent — это текстовая часть запроса, которую веб-приложения используют для сообщения сайту информации о себе. Если libcurl так не делает, может быть запрет, нужно видимо как-то сказать что ты браузер через libcurl сообщив параметр User-Agent